# Show that $f (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniform continous if and only if there is a continous $g|_{(a,b)} = f$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The assignment is:

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$ and $f: (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Show that: The function $f$ is uniform continous if and only if there exists a continous function $ g: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $ g|_{(a,b)} = f.$

The $\rightarrow$ - proof is not difficult, but I could use help with the $\leftarrow$ - proof.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the $\Leftarrow$-proof is not difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a sequence $x_1, \dotsc, x_n, \dotsc$ converging to $a$ (or $b$) uniform continuity tells you that $f(x_1) \dotsc, f(x_n), \dotsc$ is a Cauchy sequence (you should do the computation), therefore has a limit, and setting $g(a)$ (resp. $b$) equal to that limit should work.